# Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm breaking my head with Spring security settings.

I have my custum login page, with inMemoryAuthentification works.
I have oauth2Login with google works.
But the 2 don't want to work together.
If I comment **.oauth2Login()** in memoryWork.
If I uncomment **.oauth2Login()** whether I comment **.formLogin()** or not, inMemory no longer works but oauth works
If someone has an idea

```
    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder, dataSource: DataSource) {

        val encoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder()
        
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(encoder)
            .withUser("admin")
            .authorities(ROLE.Admin.role)
            .roles(ROLE.Admin.role)
            .password(encoder.encode("abc"))
    }



    @Bean
    open fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {

    return http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        //login oauth
        .antMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        **.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            //.usernameParameter("name")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/process-login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .permitAll()**
        .and()
        **.oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/process-login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .permitAll()**
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .build()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After million of test, this works.

```
.oauth2Login()
   .loginPage("/login")
// .loginProcessingUrl("/process-login")
   .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
   .permitAll()
.and()
.formLogin()
   .loginPage("/login")
   .loginProcessingUrl("/process-login")
   .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
   .permitAll()
            .and()
```